# Batch File path vairiable %PATH%

Tags: batch-file, path, chat, notepad

I have been creating a chat room for my school, but I have to bring home the file to make changes as they become needed but my problem is the file path has to be changed each time I move the files from one system to another. so I would like to know how to create a `%PATH%` that will work for me

This is my full code for the main file:

As you may notice I'm new to this

**NOTE**: Everything here works fine with a set file path but I want it to work easier for when I change computers.

Anything could probably help

```
@echo off

:Tittle
cls
color 74
title Terms of Service
echo _________________________-Terms-______________________________
echo If you are using this ChatRoom then you agree to the following.
echo *you will not use Horrid Language
echo *you will make your account with either your real name or
echo Student id
echo.
echo This is monitored everyday so if anything is out of line it will be removed.
echo.
echo If you agree to follow these terms then type "yes" otherwise exit.

set /p c=Do you Agree to follow the terms?:
if %c% EQU yes goto Menu
if %c% EQU ADMIN1423 goto Admin
if %c% EQU dad goto Menu
if %c% EQU carrie goto Menu
if %c% EQU dad SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\Users\Dan W Frye\Desktop\(-_-)
:Admin
color 02
cls    
Echo

Echo.
Echo 1.) Check User list
Echo.
Echo 2.) Create File Path                          
Echo.
Echo 3.) Admin Help
Echo.
echo 4.) N/A
echo.
Echo 

set /p c=Selection Number:
if %c% EQU 1 goto UserList
if %c% EQU 2 goto CreatePath
if %c% EQU 3 goto AdminHelp
if %c% EQU 4 goto Admin
if %c% EQU back goto Tittle

:UserList
color 0b
cls
title User Listing
cls
start cmd
CALL "%PATH%\Data\Chat Settings\Users\BuAsTeCrHs.bat"
pause
goto Admin

:CreatePath
cls
color 01
echo 
echo.
echo The File Path Must look like this(No " "): "Driver (C:)"\Containing folder" thats it the     echo rest is automatically "\Data\Chat Settings\Users\....."
echo.
echo 
echo.
echo The File Path you want to create.
set /p PATH=File Path:

echo.
echo The Location/Device you are using.
set /p LOC=Location:

echo.
echo %PATH% >>"%PATH%\Data\Chat Settings\File Paths\%LOC%.txt"
echo The file path has been created!
pause
goto Admin
:AdminHelp

pause
goto Tittle
:Menu
color 0b

cls

Echo -[ChatBox]-
Echo 
Echo.
Echo 1.) Login
Echo.
Echo 2.) Register
Echo.
Echo 3.) Exit
Echo.
echo 4.) Help
echo.
Echo 
Echo.
set /p c=Selection Number:
if %c% EQU 1 goto Login
if %c% EQU 2 goto Register
if %c% EQU 3 exit
if %c% EQU 4 goto help
if %c% EQU 5 goto Terms
:help
cls
echo    if you are not able to see the chat log then you must not have
echo the file "Chatroom_reader.bat" open without this you cannot see
echo messages sent by other users.
echo.
echo    if you have suggestions or comments then please type "comment"
echo.
echo    if you need assistance with any other problem you may have
echo encountered then please type "other" to let the developer know
echo what the problem is. otherwise type "back" to go back to the menu.
set /p c=Option:
if %c% EQU comment goto comments
if %c% EQU other goto other
if %c% EQU back goto menu
:comments
cls
title Comments
echo Enter your Username, and Password to Place a Comment
echo.
set /p UN=Username:
echo.
set /p PW=Password:
echo.
if NOT Exist "%PATH%\Data\Chat Settings\Users\%UN%.txt" Goto Failed 
echo %PW% >"%tmp%\chat.tmp"
fc "%tmp%\chat.tmp" "%PATH%\Data\Chat Settings\Users\%UN%.txt" >nul
if errorlevel==1 goto Failed
if errorlevel==0 goto Comment

:Comment
cls
echo.
set /p SUBJECT=Subject:
echo.
set /p COMMENT=Comment:
echo.
echo %SUBJECT% : %COMMENT% >"%PATH%\Data\Chat Settings\Comments\%UN%.txt"
goto User
:other
cls
title Other
echo Enter your Username, and Password to Place a Comment
echo.
set /p UN=Username:
echo.
set /p PW=Password:
echo.
if NOT Exist "C:\Users\Dan W Frye\Desktop\(-_-)\Data\Chat Settings\Users\%UN%.txt" Goto Failed 
echo %PW% >"%tmp%\chat.tmp"
fc "%tmp%\chat.tmp" "C:\Users\Dan W Frye\Desktop\(-_-)\Data\Chat Settings\Users\%UN%.txt" >nul
if errorlevel==1 goto Failed
if errorlevel==0 goto OtherA

:OtherA
cls
set /p OTHERC=Other Concern:
echo.
echo %OTHERC% >"%PATH%\Data\Chat Settings\Other\%UN%.txt"
goto User
:Login
cls
echo Enter your Username, and Password to login to the Chat Server
echo.
set /p UN=Username:
echo.
set /p PW=Password:
echo.

if NOT Exist "%PATH%\Data\Chat Settings\Users\%UN%.txt" Goto Failed 
echo %PW% >"%tmp%\chat.tmp"
fc "%tmp%\chat.tmp" "%PATH%\Data\Chat Settings\Users\%UN%.txt" >nul
if errorlevel==1 goto Failed
if errorlevel==0 goto User

:User
cls
Echo Welcome %UN%                                     The Current date is %date%
echo 
echo.
echo 1.) Chat
echo.
echo 2.) Logout
echo.
echo 3.) Change Password
echo.
echo 4.) Private Chat
echo.
echo 5.) Enter a Private Chat room
echo.
echo 
set /p c=Selection Number:
if %c% EQU 1 goto chat
if %c% EQU 2 goto Menu
if %c% EQU 3 goto CHP
if %c% EQU 4 goto PRIVATE
if %c% EQU 5 goto PRIVATENTER

:PRIVATENTER
echo Please enter the name of the Private chat room if you do not know the name you may not     enter.
set /p Chat=
if %Chat% EQU scooter goto scooter
if %Chat% EQU Cre-Br goto Cre-Br

:Cre-Br
cls
set name=[%time%]%UN%
cls
color 02
echo Last Message sent by %UN% \/
echo [%time%]%UN%:%text%
set /p text=Say:

echo %name% : %text% >>"%PATH%\Data\Chat Settings\Program_Files\Cre-Br.txt"
goto Cre-Br


:scooter
cls 
echo %Chat%

set name=[%time%]%UN%

color 02
echo Last Message sent by %UN% \/
echo [%time%]%UN%:%text%
set /p text=Say:

echo %name% : %text% >>"%PATH%\Data\Chat Settings\Program_Files\scooter.txt"
goto scooter

:PRIVATE
cls
set /p Chat=Chat Name:

echo this is %UN%s Private chat room >>"%PATH%\Data\Chat Settings\Program_Files\%Chat%.txt"
echo.
echo @echo off >>"%PATH%\Data\Chat Settings\Private Chats\%Chat%.bat"
echo color 0b >>"%PATH%H:\(-_-)\Data\Chat Settings\Private Chats\%Chat%.bat"
echo cls >>"%PATH%\Data\Chat Settings\Private Chats\%Chat%.bat"
echo title Message Box >>"%PATH%\Data\Chat Settings\Private Chats\%Chat%.bat"
echo :home >>"%PATH%\Data\Chat Settings\Private Chats\%Chat%.bat"
echo cls >>"%PATH%\Data\Chat Settings\Private Chats\%Chat%.bat"
echo findstr /v "g91dhjt637hsuexv27niw9" "%PATH%\Data\Chat Settings\Program_Files\%Chat%.txt"     >>"C:\Users\Dan W Frye\Desktop\Batch\Chat Settings\Private Chats\%Chat%.bat"
echo goto home >>"%PATH%\Data\Chat Settings\Private Chats\%Chat%.bat"

goto User

:CHP
cls
set /p PW=Old Password:
echo.
set /p NP=New Password:
echo %NP% >"%PATH%\Data\Chat Settings\Users\%UN%.txt
goto User

:Register
cls
color 07

echo Register (Note the username is your screen name Please use your real name or School ID EX,     CaBu56789)
echo.
set /p NU=Username:
echo.
set /p NP=Password:
echo.
echo %NP% >"%PATH%\Data\Chat Settings\Users\%NU%.txt"
echo.
cls
goto login

:Failed
color 0c
cls
echo You have entered am invalid Username and or Password
echo Please try again or Register for free
pause
goto menu

:chat
set name=[%time%]%UN%
cls
color 02
echo Everything said here is on recored please mind your
echo language!
echo Last Message sent by %UN% \/
echo [%time%]%UN%:%text%
set /p text=Say:

echo %name% : %text% >>"%PATH%\Data\Chat Settings\Program_Files\ChatRoom.txt"

goto chat
```

Answer (score 0):

%PATH% is reserved environment variable, documented here: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/path.mspx?mfr=true

For diagnostics purposes you could echo that variable to analyze if that has such value you intended to have:

```
echo %path%
```

Comment: I just did that and the path it gave me was

    C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows     Live;C:\Program Files (x8
    6)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows     Live;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\
    windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0    \;C:\Program Fil
    es (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;c:\Users\Dan W Frye\Desktop\(-_-)

Answer (score 0):

In your code the path was being set after it had already branched to the menu. This may work for you:

```
if %c% EQU carrie goto Menu
if %c% EQU dad SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\Users\Dan W Frye\Desktop\(-_-)& goto menu
```

To put the batch file on the path for every user, use this:

```
set path=%path%;%PUBLIC%
```

and copy the batch file to `C:\Users\Public` and run it from there.
Unless it needs extra permissions it should run from there for every user.

Comment: SO what you mean is to make the two action happen at the same time not one after the other? because I can see how that would work

Comment: The variable is added to the PATH statement, and then it branches to the :menu label.  In your code the line that changes the PATH statement when dad logs in is never executed.

Comment: well what @Durry42 said was "SET "progpath=c:\Users\%username%\Desktop\(-_-)"" is there a way to do that same thing for the hard disk? like:    SET progpath=%HARDDISK%\Users\%username%\Desktop\(-_-)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Jermu Virtanen the `%PATH%` variable is a windows system set path...you should not use/change it unless you really know what you are doing.
So instead of using `%PATH%` use something like `%PROGPATH%`.

Also as mentioned by @foxdrive, if the user enters "dad" it will go to "menu" before setting the path variable. And again if you instead chose 'Admin' then to 'List users' it will again be calling the path without first setting it.

You could automate some of the login or path settings by grabbing the computer's domain name `%userdomain%` and current user `%username%`.

Ie;

```
SET "progpath=c:\Users\%username%\Desktop\(-_-)"
```

Comment: I would say that would work for me but the school that I go to has a network setup so how I think it looks is `"H:\(-_-)"` that's why I have it set as `%PATH%\Data\Chat Settings\`  so I can set the path. the `%PATH%` changes from computer  to computer. the schools network is not located on `C:`

Comment: other then the school network problem what you said works! but... it wont login even when the ERRORLEVEL==0 it goes to failed and I don't understand why

Comment: Using PATH by adding another folder to the end of it is fine and is the point of the PATH variable.  What Durry42 means is that you shouldn't use system variables like `path` `date` `time` etc as general variables for other purposes.  @Durry42 please edit your answer to reflect this.  I edited my answer with a possible solution for your problem.